# remove , from string via def - tokenized

Tags: python, parsing

Trying to tokenize and strip comma off value 
current output with

```
def clean(string):
result = ""
for i,char in enumerate(line):
    if char == " ":
        if string[i+1].isdigit() or string[i+1] == " ":
            continue
    result += char
return result
```

> latitude  +41.136778, -95.948622  65.000000   red 
>   latitude  +41.136778, -95.948622  65.000000   red 
>   latitude  +41.136778, -95.948622  65.000000   blue
>   latitude  +41.136778, -95.948622  65.000000   red

If I try to add a comma to the string as such:

```
def clean(string):
result = ""
for i,char in enumerate(line):
    if char == " ":
        if string[i+1].isdigit() or or string[i+1] + "," string[i+1] == " ":
            continue
    result += char
return result
```

I get the following:

> latitude  +41.137342,longitude=-95.947951bar=65.000000foo=23.849165secscolor=red   latitude   +41.137338,longitude=-95.947936bar=65.000000foo=0.036936secscolor=blue   latitude   +41.137338,longitude=-95.947936bar=65.000000foo=58.715930secscolor=blue

Desired output:

> latitude  +41.136778  longitude bar -95.948622    foo 65.000000   color blue
>      latitude   +41.136778  longitude bar -95.948622    foo 65.000000   color red

Thanks

Comment: Fixed, it was correct in the script, but not in the example I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to have completely understood, but I think the following built-in fonction might be what you're looking for:

```
return string.replace(",", " ")
```

PS: you can use it multiple times:

```
return string.replace(",", " ").replace("=", " ")
```